# Count number of occurrences of a char in the sequence

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have to write unix script for count number of occurrences of `G` char in the sequence: `"GTCGTAATGCGGATCGGAATCGA"`

and i want output as `"number of nucleotide G is 8"`

Comment: nucleotides. it means occurance of "G"

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

With bash

```
var='GTCGTAATGCGGATCGGAATCGA'
var="${var//[^G]}"
echo "Number of nucleotide G is ${#var}"
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ print "Number of nucleotide G is "gsub("G", "") }' <<<"GTCGTAATGCGGATCGGAATCGA"
Number of nucleotide G is 8
```

---

**`grep`** + **`wc`** solution:

```
printf "Number of nucleotide G is %d\n" $(grep -o 'G' <<<"GTCGTAATGCGGATCGGAATCGA" | wc -l)
Number of nucleotide G is 8
```

Comment: what if I want output as " number of nucleotide G = 8"

Comment: @ThanisPrucksikanont, anything else?

Comment: yes, i want my output as " Number of nucleotide G is 8" like this

Comment: @ThanisPrucksikanont, if you wanted that - that should have been mentioned in your question

Comment: I already edit.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
echo 'GTCGTAATGCGGATCGGAATCGA' | perl -ne 'printf "number of nucleotide G is %d\n", ($_ =~ tr/G/G/)'
```

This counts the Gs by using Perl's `tr` operator. It returns the number of replacements made, and we're replacing any G with a G.

The output will be

```
number of nucleotide G is 8
```

If you would want to generalize this to also count other bases, then *don't* run this multiple times on genome sized data, but go to the [Bioinformatics StackExchange site](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) and look for answers there.